# Rails Rspec Controller return 'undefined method Sinatra::Application:Class'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller, mocha.js

Typically I avoid controller tests and stick to Model & Cucumber, but i find myself needing one and I cant seem to get moving.

The following code is simplistic.. i have ripped out just about everything

```
1 require 'spec_helper'
2
3 describe ExperiencesController do
4   describe "GET #show" do
5     context "experience item" do
6       it "redirects to the success url" do
7         experience = build(:experience)
8         get :show, :id => experience.id
9         #should be a test here :)
10       end
11     end
12   end
13 end
```

**Yields the following**

```
Failures:

  1) ExperiencesController GET #show experience item redirects to the success url
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => experience.id
     NoMethodError:
     undefined method `id' for Sinatra::Application:Class
      # (__DELEGATE__):2:in `get'
      # ./spec/controller_spec/experiences_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (4 levels) in      <top (required)>'

$ rake routes|grep experience
                 experiences GET      /experiences(.:format)                                      experiences#index
                             POST     /experiences(.:format)                                      experiences#create
              new_experience GET      /experiences/new(.:format)                                  experiences#new
             edit_experience GET      /experiences/:id/edit(.:format)                             experiences#edit
                  experience GET      /experiences/:id(.:format)                                  experiences#show
                             PUT      /experiences/:id(.:format)                                  experiences#update
                             DELETE   /experiences/:id(.:format)                                  experiences#destroy
```

**Really feels like a config type of thing**
I dont understand why it would be yielding a Sinatra error
Any help appreciated

** Update **

SideKiq and its dependency sinatra is installed in the Gemfile for this rails app.
And I believe that sinatra may be interfering with controller test.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. so the problem was a collision of mistakes

**1.) Because Im using Sidekiq I had the following in my config route**

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
```

That awesome piece of code mounts a Sinatra based web interface to monitor Sidekiq

**2.) If you notice above my directory above is wrong**

```
It was incorrectly spec/controller_spec instead of spec/controller

When that happens rspec doesnt know you are intending to test controllers and doesnt
load all the Get/post helpers , instead in the loaded stack the only thing it 
found was sinatra which has a get method..
```

Solution .. 
    Move the spec to the proper directory so it properly infers the right dependencies

IT10T error..